# DataAnnotations Date Range

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In my MVC4 project I have a Meta class where I have my date format specified with DataAnnotations. I want to limit the range to the SQL DateTime type.

```
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1753", "12/31/9999", ErrorMessage = "Check Date")]
    public DateTime SeniorityDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

The format works fine without the range validation. When I add the range validation and I enter an invalid date I get the error message specified. The issues is when I fix the date again to something like 01/27/2008 then the validator still indicates the date is not valid. I assumed this is because I am not entering nor do I want a time component. Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying code listed here to meet my needs.
http://www.headspringlabs.com/blog/mvc-custom-unobtrusive-validator-attribute-date-range-validation/

Comment: That page is no longer found.